# how to create an empty array

Tags: lint, gawk

**UPDATE**

The original description below has many errors; gawk lint does not complain about uninitialized arrays used as RHS of `in`. For example, the following example gives no errors or warnings. I am not deleting the question because the answer I am about to accept gives good suggestion of using `split` with an empty string to create an empty array.

```
BEGIN{
    LINT = "fatal"; 
    // print x; // LINT gives error if this is uncommented 
    thread = 0;
    if (thread in threads_start) { 
        print "if"; 
    } else {  
        print "not if"; 
    }
}
```

---

**Original Question**

A lot of my awk scripts have a construct as follows:

```
if (thread in threads_start) {  // LINT warning here
  printf("%s started at %d\n", threads[thread_start]));
} else {
  printf("%s started at unknown\n");
}
```

With `gawk --lint` which results in

> warning: reference to uninitialized variable `thread_start'

So I initialize in the BEGIN block as follows. But this looks kludge-y. Is there a more elegant way to create a zero-element array?

```
BEGIN { LINT = 1; thread_start[0] = 0; delete thread_start[0]; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary**

The idiomatic method of [creating an empty array in Awk](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_13.html#SEC126) is to use `split()`.

**Details**

To simplify your example above to focus on your question rather than your typos, the fatal error can be triggered with:

```awk
BEGIN{
    LINT = "fatal"; 
    if (thread in threads_start) { 
        print "if"; 
    } else {  
        print "not if"; 
    }
}
```

which produces the following error:

`` gawk: cmd. line:3: fatal: reference to uninitialized variable `thread' ``

Giving `thread` a value before using it to search in `threads_start` passes linting:

```awk
BEGIN{
    LINT = "fatal"; 
    thread = 0;
    if (thread in threads_start) { 
        print "if"; 
    } else {  
        print "not if"; 
    }
}
```

produces:

`not if`

To create a linting error with an uninitialised array, we need to attempt to access an non-existent entry:

```awk
BEGIN{
    LINT = "fatal"; 
    thread = 0;
    if (threads_start[thread]) { 
        print "if"; 
    } else {  
        print "not if"; 
    }
}
```

produces:

`` gawk: cmd. line:4: fatal: reference to uninitialized element `threads_start["0"]' ``

So, you don't really *need* to create an empty array in Awk, but if you *want* to do so, and answer your question, use `split()`:

```awk
BEGIN{
    LINT = "fatal"; 
    thread = 0;
    split("", threads_start);
    if (thread in threads_start) { 
        print "if"; 
    } else {  
        print "not if"; 
    }
}
```

produces:

`not if`

Comment: Thank you for bringing me back to this dumb question. Thank you for ignoring the errors and still providing useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have made a few typo's in your code.

```
if (thread in threads_start) { // LINT warning here (you think)
```

Here you look for the index `thread` in array `threads_start`.

```
  printf("%s started at %d\n", threads[thread_start])); // Actual LINT warning
```

But here you print the index `thread_start` in array `threads`! Also notice the different **s**'s `thread`/`threads` and `threads_start`/`thread_start`. Gawk is actually warning you correctly about the usage of `thread_start` (without s) on the second line.

There also is an error in your `printf` format.

When you change these the lint warning disappears:

```
if (thread in threads_start) {
  printf("%s started at %d\n", thread, threads_start[thread]));
} else {
  printf("%s started at unknown\n");
}
```

But perhaps I've misunderstood what your code is supposed to do. In that case, could you post a minimal self-contained code sample that produces the spurious lint warning?