# Trying to force an entry in an array to be an array

Tags: multidimensional-array, awk, associative-array

I am trying to create an associative array of associative arrays in gawk, and what I initially tried was:

```
options[key][subkey] = 1
```

However, when it got to this line, I unceremoniously received the error `fatal: attempt to use scalar 'option["Declaration"]' as an array` ("Declaration" being one of the main keys that my program uses, although I presume the exact value is irrelevant.   At this particular point in the program, there was no "Declaration" entry assigned, although there were entries which had "Declaration" as a subkey on other entries, which may be meaningful).

So with a bit of googling, I found another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822485/how-to-create-an-empty-array) that looked like it answered my issue, so I put the following code immediately above it:

```
if (typeof(options[key])!="array") {
    options[key] = 0;
    delete options[key];
    split("",options[key]);
}
```

However, this does not work either, instead now giving me the error: `fatal: split: second argument is not an array`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:  Note, that I cannot use a basic 2-dimensional array here... for what I am doing, it is important that I am using one associative array to another because I need to be able to later identify the subkeys that were used on a given key.

Pursuant to requests below, I am posting the relevant functions that use the associative array, which may help clarify what is going on.

```
function add_concrete(key, concrete) {
    if (key == concrete) {
        return;
    }
    if (length(options[key])>0) {
        for(i in options[key]) {
            add_concrete(i, concrete);
        }
    }
    contains[key][concrete] = 1
}

function add_options(name, value) {
    subkey = trim(name);
    if (subkey == "") {
        return;
    }
    if (match(value, ";") > 0) {
        exporting = 0;
    }
    split(value, args, /[ |;]*/);
    for (i in args) {
        key = trim(args[i]);
        if (key != "") {
            print("Adding " name " to " key);
            options[key][subkey] = 1
            if (concrete[key]) {
                add_concrete(subkey, key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The arguments to `split()` is wrong. The arguments order is `split(<str>, <array-to-store-results>, <delimiter-to-split>)`

Comment: Just do `options[key, subkey] = 1`

Comment: You need to "initialize" the array. put `options[key][1]` before the `split()`.

Comment: @markt1964, IMHO, request you to please add your complete picture of your question so that we will get more thoughts on it and could help you too.

Comment: @KamilCuk that would be using a pseudo-multi-dimensional array instead of an array of arrays. The latter is gawk-only but far more useful. (e.g. `for (i in arr) for (j in arr[i]) ...`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, cooking at the same time. As you didn't post much, don't have much to work with, but with no "initialization":

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    options[key] = 0;
    delete options[key];
#    options[key][1]          # cant see me
    split("",options[key]);
}'
awk: cmd. line:5: fatal: split: second argument is not an array
```

But with "initialization":

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    options[key] = 0;
    delete options[key];
    options[key][1]          # can see me
    split("",options[key]);
}'
$_ # see this cursor happily blinking without any error
```

Comment: Right. See the usage example at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays-of-Arrays.